# Capistrano's Current Symlink not recognized by the IDE and my FTP Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, symlink, rubymine

The symbolic link to `current` is not recognized by my FTP client or my IDE (RubyMine).

Is there a way to create a symlink through Capistrano that "looks and acts" like a real folder?

[image: symlink-not-working]

Answer (score -1):

The symlink that is created to denote the current release (as long as it works from the command line) - does it matter that your specific IDE does not recognize it?

What you are asking for is for your IDE to "follow" symlinks and populate the files/folders within it/them - can you please define why you would need such a behavior?

Comment: I want to be able to browse the files like I can in the Terminal. The IDE should not treat a symlink to a folder like a file IMHO.

Comment: But that is VERY specific to the IDE and how that is implemented. I do understand your request, but it would be a feature request for the folks @ JetBrains